# Resizing /Dev/SDA1 : Google Cloud

Tags: unix, google-cloud-platform

I am a total noob on this one. I have a google cloud SUSE instance which is running a VM image. I am trying to install a package but I think it's running out of space. 
What I want to do is to assign some of the 120G space to my /dev/sda1 partition. I have read the [google's guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk) but I am not sure which section should I be following.

```
>df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         13G     0   13G   0% /dev
tmpfs            13G     0   13G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            13G  9.7M   13G   1% /run
tmpfs            13G     0   13G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        36G   34G     0 100% /
tmpfs           2.6G     0  2.6G   0% /run/user/490
tmpfs           2.6G     0  2.6G   0% /run/user/1004
tmpfs           2.6G     0  2.6G   0% /run/user/1006

>sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  120G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0   36G  0 part /
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry this was a long time ago and I think I just gave up on this quest!

Comment: But i have shared the answer maybe you can update the staus of question which resolves the issue for others also if you don't mind please : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60543181/5525824

Answer (score 9):

Without reboot increase boot size in GCP cloud VM

Check first disk usage using `df -h` if usage of `/dev/sda1` more than 80% it's dangerous.

Update disk size on the fly

1. Increase disk size from console first
2. SSH inside VM : `sudo growpart /dev/sda 1`
3. Resize your file system : `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1`
4. Verify : `df -h`

Comment: I CANT BELIEVE IT'S JUST THAT SIMPLE!! Spent more than four days reading over several answers, nothing could help, almost had given up, until I found this. I couldn't thank you more

Comment: The best answer among all the answers out there.

Answer (score 6):

Increase the size of existing persistent disk:

1. Login to Google Cloud Platform
2. Goto Compute Engine -> Disks
3. Locate your VM's boot disk(default disk), open it
4. Click Edit
5. Enter a new size, please note that you won't be able to ***decrease*** this size later.
6. Reboot your VM, you should be able to see new size of disk.

Comment: Thanks. It was already at 120GB (see the image with the original post). I just want to reallocate some of the 120GB to sda1.

Comment: By any chance, did you find out how to do that with google cloud?

Comment: It might be too late now but I was not able to make it work. I switched to AWS and their partitioning seemed better. Although I had to abandon the project in between!

Comment: `sudo resize2fs /dev/[DISK_ID]`

where `[DISK_ID]` is the ID of the disk where you are resizing the file system.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an addition to Prateeks answer. After changing the size, you need to run (linux only) to reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

Give it some time, close your console if you get no response. Then run `df` again to see the new size.

Answer (score 2):

Super late to the party but using `sudo growpart /dev/sda 1` worked for me

Comment: Super Super late ! The system is long gone ! I will try it next time I run into something like this. Hopefully your answer will help someone else.